# Получение ответа от сервера?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, get

При клике на кнопку происходит загрузка файла на сервер в ответ я получаю

```
{files: [{name: "screenshot (1).png", size: 1004591, type: "image/png",…}]}
files:[{name: "screenshot (1).png", size: 1004591, type: "image/png",…}]
0:{name: "screenshot (1).png", size: 1004591, type: "image/png",…}
deleteType:"DELETE"
deleteUrl:"http://someurldelete.png"
name:"screenshot (1).png"
size:1004591
thumbnailUrl:"someurl.png"
type:"image/png"
url:"someurl.png"
```

Вопрос в том как мне получить thumbnailUrl:"someurl.png" и перезаписать, а потом только отправить пользователю.

Comment: Вы можете прочитать его, и записать туда своё значение - тогда оно само отправится пользователю

Answer (score 0):

если Вам приходит такая строка, то Вы где то пропустили скобку (можете проверить здесь http://jsonlint.com/). В случае если Вы случайно ошиблись,- сделайте

JSON.parse(ваша строка)

и можно будет достать и перезаписать свойство по ссылке, например

```
var recievedObj = JSON.parse(string);
    recievedObj.thumbnailUrl = 'changed';
```